# Are any boons/curses issued in Rig Veda?

Tags: rig-veda, identification-request, curse, boon

The poets pray for cattle and so forth and pray to rudra not to harm them but there doesn't seem to be boons and curses recorded in rig veda.  One would think boons and curses would be mostly epic/puranic.  So, do we find boons/curses anywhere in Rig Veda?

Comment: You can select the given answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Do we find boons/curses anywhere in Rig Veda?

Yes we do find  boons ,curses in Rig Veda Samhita.

#### Curses

For instance a curse from Yayati to Yadu or turvash is mentioned in [**Rig-Veda Mandala 4 -Sukta 30 - Mantra 17**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v4.100)  ,Which is mandala of Rishi Vamdeva .

Here Yayati is cursing Yadu or Turvash ,to whom Indra made eligible for Abisheka.

> उत तया तुर्वशायदू अस्नातारा शचीपतिः |  इन्द्रो विद्वां अपारयत || RV
>   4.30.17||
>
> uta tyā turvaśāyadū asnātārā śacīpatiḥ |  indro vidvāṃ apārayat ||
>
> Wise Shachipti Indra made  the famous ruler Yadu Or Turvash , who has
>   fall down by  the curse of Yayati eligible again to receive Abhisheka
>   .

---

And here [**Rig-Veda Mandala 7- Sukta 8 - Mantra 5**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v7.26)   is telling us the story of Indra realising the curse given to Sudasa by Tarangit Rivers.

> अर्णांसि चित पप्रथाना सुदास इन्द्रो गाधान्यक्र्णोत सुपारा | 
>   शर्धन्तं शिम्युमुचथस्य नव्यः **शापं** सिन्धूनामक्र्णोदशस्तीः || RV 7.8.5||
>
> arṇāṃsi cit paprathānā sudāsa indro ghādhānyakṛṇot supārā | 
>   śardhantaṃ śimyumucathasya navyaḥ **śāpaṃ** sindhūnāmakṛṇodaśastīḥ ||
>
> What though the floods spread widely, Indra made them shallow and easy
>   for Sudās to traverse.
>   He, worthy of our praises, caused the Simyu, foe of our hymn, **to curse the rivers' fury.** [English](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07018.htm)

---

And now here  [**Rig-Veda Mandala 4 - Sukata 18 - Mantra 7**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v4.82) is the mentioning  the famous curse of Indra which he got after killing Vrtra.( curse of BrahmaHatya.)

> किम उ षविद अस्मै निविदो भनन्तेन्द्रस्यावद्यं दिधिषन्त आपः | 
>   ममैतान पुत्रो महता वधेन वर्त्रं जघन्वां अस्र्जद वि सिन्धून ||RV 4.18.7||
>
> kim u ṣvid asmai nivido bhanantendrasyāvadyaṃ didhiṣanta āpaḥ | 
>   mamaitān putro mahatā vadhena vṛtraṃ jaghanvāṃ asṛjad vi sindhūn
>   ||
>
> What are the words of veda are saying about the curse of Indra which
>   he got from killing Vratra?   This curse is received by the water in
>   the form of bubbles . My son Indra killed Vratra with his vajra and
>   released the streams.

---

#### Boons

Similar way the Rig-Veda samhita is also  mentioning the boons Here in [**Rig-Veda 8.91**](http://www.streeshakti.com/bookA.aspx?author=28)  . **Indra's boon to brahmavadini Apala** is mentioned.

> In the hymn she narrates how she met and worshipped Indra and how his
>   boon freed her of her disease. Knowing soma juice to be Indra’s
>   favourite drink, Apala gathered the soma plant and crushed it between
>   her teeth to extract the juice. Attracted by the sound, Indra appeared
>   to her and drank the juice from Apala’s lips. **In return he blessed
>   Apala with three boons**: that her father’s head, his fields and her
>   skin would be ‘fruitful’.

---

And below are the screenshots of Mantras.

**RV 4.30.17** 
[image]

---

**RV 7.8.5**

[image]

---

**RV 4.18.7**
[image]