# Is there a human mentioned in the Vedas that has got the boon from the God?

Tags: vedas, human, boon

There are many asura's that got boon from the God but are there humans that got boon from God.

Comment: See this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24128

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thanks  for the answer