# Is Lord Krishna from South of India since lot of Kshatriya Yadav families were from the South?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, yadavas

It is quite possible that Lord Krishna later must have gone to North and thence to Dwarka. Also his color was brown which might indicate a south Indian origin .

Comment: Lord Krishna was from Goloka, which is very far away from India! :)

Comment: yayati , if i am not wrong was a king who was ruling in the lands between Rajastan and Iran . his son yadu was given the south of india from which line krishna descended.

Answer (score 4):

Yadu's descendants came to be known as the Yadavas. For more more details see [What is the historical origin of Yadavas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22896/12304)

[SB 9.19.22](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/19/22) says that

> King Yayāti gave the south to his son Yadu.

As Yadu was appointed the king of South so it's oblivious that many Kshatriya Yadav families were/are from the South.

However it's nothing to do with Lord Krishna's birth. Lord Krishna took birth in Mathurā and was raised in Gokul, Vṛndāvana (~ [SB 10](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10)). Lord Krishna's ancestors (much much earlier; not his father, grand father, ..) might have moved from South to North.

Later Lord Krishna moved to Dvārakā from Mathurā (~[SB 10.50](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50)).